# Regex: Find motiv surrounded by similar characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of the form

```
'---EECCCC---CCEEECCC-------EEEEECCEECC-----'
```

I want to extract all instances of "EECC", plus any 'E's before and 'C's afterwards. That would be:

```
['EECCCC', 'EEECCC', 'EEEEECC','EECC'].
```

I feel like there must be an easy way using python's regex package, but I can't get a grip on it. Any ideas? :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a lot of examples of using regular expressions in python.

Comment: If you spend some half an hour at http://regexone.com, you will learn how to do that and many more things with regex.

Comment: I tried constructing search strings that look for "somethings that is not E" + "E"+"arbitrary number of E" + "ECC" + "arbitrary number of Cs" + "something that is not C".

Comment: And what did the solution look like? Please update the question.

Comment: Thanks @ Wiktor Stribiżew, I will definitely do that. For the moment, I'm looking for a quick solution for my specific problem. If it is also difficult for other people, then I will try find my way through regex myself ofc.

Comment: It is basic. Just read about quantifiers at [Lesson 7](https://regexone.com/lesson/kleene_operators).

Comment: Thank you! This seems to cover perfectly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the regex rule you're probably searching for is as follows:

```
E*EECCC*
```

Which could translate to "Zero or more E's followed by the string literal 'EECC' followed by zero or more C's".

For extracting matches in python, you should use the findall method from the re module:

```
import re
s = "---EECCCC---CCEEECCC-------EEEEECCEECC----"
print(re.findall("E*EECCC*", s))
```

The output will be:

```
['EECCCC', 'EEECCC', 'EEEEECC', 'EECC']
```

One tip is that you can test your regular expression rules online at some sites like http://www.regextester.com/ , which may help you in the future ;-)

Comment: great, thank you! I knew the answer can't be so complicated... :) Also the regextester looks very useful.